# How to Remove A Non-Empty Directory that Requires Admin Access in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I currently am trying to remove a folder through python that is Non-Empty and needs admin access. I have tried using shutil.rmtree and changing the onerror to allow admin access, but then non-empty error flag is thrown. And when I address that error by adding ignore_erros=True, the admin access error stops the files from actually being deleted. How would I go about deleting these files? The files being created are from Tensorflow's premade estimators and are taking up a lot of space on my computer as I have a program that is constantly rerunning new models. I am trying to add a script to this program that deletes the temp files after each model has been trained and overall accuracy has been collected.

Comment: Have you tried running python as administrator?

Comment: I can't even delete the folders in my file explorer after granting admin privledges. It says I need permission from <NAME>PC.

Comment: In that case - this really isn't an issue in python. You'll probably need to grant yourself access to the files. "taking ownership of files" would probably be a good search term.